# Can I put return hot wire from the switch in different color (red for example)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, code-compliance, junction-box

I am trying to install a new light spot in my basement with its own switch. So I understand the whole thing with black-white-copper wire color, so I only need to make another junction box, pull white and copper to the light and black goes to switch. So on the way back from it, can I use the red wire? I practically have to go to the same junction box and split hot in two, because I have 2 lights, but I don't want to mix which hot goes from the switch, just in case. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you do understand the whole thing.  I'd do some more research.

Comment: Is this in conduit or using cables?

Comment: Yes -- are you using a cable that consists of several wires bundled together, or pulling individual wires thru a conduit?

Comment: Your description is a little unclear and concerning. In most cases using another color (besides white, grey, green) is fine, but there are rules requiring single conductors to be in a raceway and all conductors of a circuit to be contained in the same raceway or cable. Nobody wants to give an answer that could be misunderstood to approve of a prohibited configuration, so they are probing for more information.

Comment: It seems that I just have a concern about something that seems not very important. I saw the old wiring, mostly done with NMD90 (which is in line with the code). But it was also used when there was only one wire required (and on top of that I even wanted to use red one so I recognize which one comes from the switch). I was told that it was probably cheaper to buy one type that covers them all. I have to call inspection after I'm done, so I just want to avoid any potential problems.